# Android Things - OTA via bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-things, ota

I haven't had much success searching for this.  I'm developing an Android Things application that will connect to a user phone to do certain things.  I want to use this for delivering app updates as well.

So far, my crude searches on this have just discussed OTA via the Console and thus internet.

My gut has said that I could just build this - I could have a new version of the APK, transfer it to my device via bluetooth, and then just have the device copy it over the old one and reboot.  But, not sure.  I was hoping maybe there was an API for this and I'm just not wise enough to know how to find it via the searches.

Comment: There isn't an API to do an OTA over bluetooth. There may be libraries fir sending files, but the rest you'd have to do yourself. All AndroidThings boards have to have an onboard WiFi chip. Have you thought of hotspotting the phone (that has BT) so that it can receive the normal AndroidThings console OTA update?

Comment: Thanks.  Saves me doing any more searches.  I'll continue to investigate the console mechanism.  One of the issues we face, and why I wanted to do this over bluetooth, is that I won't want to update every device when an update is available.  Some customers we want to keep on older versions for contract reasons (as in, they will not want to update).  And so, controlling access via an app I thought would be the best way.  But I admit to not having looked hard at how the OTA flow works, and probably everything I need to be concerned about is taken care of already.

Comment: yeah likely already taken care off. fyi all customers would be forced to take security updates. You could also have feature flags inside of your codebase so that customers features are toggled on and off - i.e. they get the update but don't get the feature due to the contract. Or alternatively - create a new version on the AT console for each customer. Sounds an interesting problem!